# Linked Server to AD reporting error even with max permissions

Tags: sql-server-2012, active-directory

I've created a linked server pointing our AD to create some reports.

the query to retrive the info is this one:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery (
ADSI,
'SELECT 
     mail
    ,mobile
    ,telephoneNumber
    ,title
    ,sn
    ,givenName
    ,SAMAccountName
FROM ''LDAP://MyDomain.local/OU=MyOU,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL''
WHERE objectClass = ''user''
AND NOT objectClass = ''computer''
'
) AS tblADS
ORDER BY SAMAccountName
```

and Im receiving the famous error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported an error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation.
```

Security tab has the most powerfull user we have, with access to everything. just as a try we gave max permissions to AD to the login running sql server. nothing can solve this issue.

I'm looking for answers for 2 days over the internet but all answers are like typos, or users with 0 permissions.

Answer (score -1):

This is what works for me, when I added the linked server I named it something recognizable. I also dropped the MyDomain.Local prior to the Distinguished location.

Since you're getting a permission issue, are you using an AD user who has AD query rights?

btw, out of curiosity, how are you intending to use the data?

[image: my query]

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer. Generally, it is more useful to have the text pasted rather than a screenshot. Then others can copy the text. The effort to redact is about the same either way, I've found.